# Select query result based on the difference of a "quantity" in same column of two tables

Tags: mysql, database

table 1:

```
emp_id  course_id
 ______  _________
12345      4
23455      5
67890      6
```

table 2:

```
course_id  course_name
_________  ___________
   1        English
   2        Mathematics
   3        Science
   4        G.K.
   5        c++
   6        JSP
   7        ASP
```

REQUIRED TABLE
table 3:

```
course_id  course_name
_________  ___________
   1        English
   2        Mathematics
   3        Science
   7        ASP
```

how to print table 3 in MySQL while considering difference of course_id from table 1 and table 2. (table2.course_id - table1.course_id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select course_id, course_name
from table2
where course_id not in (select course_id from table1)
```

Comment: Thanks! i was unaware of usage of NOT IN